# why when executing a bat that uses awk from oracle the process does not finish?

Tags: java, batch-file, oracle19c

I have developed a batch to remove duplicate rows from a file, for this I have used the awk tool, which I install and configure in the system environment variables: C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin

file bat:

```
@echo off
set "fecha=%1"
set "inputpath=%2"
set fechaInformacion=%fecha:~2,6%
set file=FICUO%fechaInformacion%.txt
set unique=.uq
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 19 19 3 3 5 12 6 9 40 4 8 13 3 3 3 3 1 3 13 13 13 13 13 13 3 13 2 8 8 8 2 8 6 11 11 11 8 4" "!seen[$1,$2,$6,$8,$9,$12,$16,$17,$33]++" %inputpath%%file% > %inputpath%%file%%unique%
```

when I execute the bat from cmd, the file is generated empty and when the process ends the file has data.

```
C:\Users\Administrador>C:\Archivos\ebc\in\clean.bat 20160401 C:\Archivos\ebc\in\
```

however when I run the bat from oracle using java, the file is created empty but the process never ends.

This the code in oracle:

```
create or replace and compile java source named shellscript as
public class ShellScript
{
  public static String removeDuplicate(String ruta, String nombre, String fecha) {
     try {
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ruta+nombre + " " + fecha + " " + ruta);
          p.waitFor();
      }catch( java.io.IOException ex ){
          return ex.getMessage();
      }catch( InterruptedException ex ){
          return ex.getMessage();
      }
      return "OK";
  }
};

FUNCTION FNC_DELETED(pva_Directorio IN VARCHAR2, pva_NombreScript IN VARCHAR2, pva_FechaInformacion IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'ShellScript.removeDuplicate(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';

SELECT FNC_DELETED(pva_Directorio       => 'C:\archivos\ebc\in\',
                   pva_NombreScript     => 'clean.bat',
                   pva_FechaInformacion => '20160401')
  FROM dual;
```

What I have been able to identify is that in the first case awk runs inside the cmd but in the second case it seems to run independently.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how can I fix it?. thanks.

Comment: I decided to do the tests with a file with less volume (3kb).  First, I added the line to get the file with the environment variables and executed the bat in the command prompt (cmd): Administrator_Variables.txt, then I executed it with Oracle: WIN-41TQ2AD16HC$_Variables.txt.

Comment: In this test I realized that with the file less, when I execute the bat from oracle, the process ends but the output file is empty, however when I execute it from cmd, the file does have data.

Comment: Execute the two lines to set the environment variables according to the file WIN-41TQ2AD16HC$_Variables.txt and simulate an Oracle environment. I verified that the variables were updated by executing SET, finally I executed the bat but the file with data was generated, when I expected it to be created empty.